# Cross Matching an ArrayList in Java 8

Tags: java, filter, foreach, java-stream

So i what to cross match data in a Generic class list where is want check matching Names to Surnames, and if there is a match either return the data or return a boolean . heres what i came up with

```
list.stream().forEach(x -> {
    boolean test = list2.stream()
            .anyMatch(tst -> tst.getLastName() == x.getStuName());
    if (test) {
        test2.setBool(test);
    }
});
System.out.println("Match > " + test2.getBool());
```

This returns TRUE because I use A GETTER AND SETTER to return the boolean from the lambda expression by setting the boolean .

So I'm looking for the simplest lambda expression to do this? please is there anyone out there .

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter:

```
  long count = list.stream().filter(e -> e.equals(someString)).count();
```

But this is done in `O(n)`. There is a better way... Instead of the ordinary list, use `Set`, so convert `List` to `Set` and check if it exists:

```
Set set = new HashSet(list);

if (set.contains(someString)) return true;
```

If you convert the list once before any checking and just use that set later, checking if it contains is done in `O(1)`. Depends how you get the list at first place? Do you have list at the start of the program? Then make it static list in class. Do you get it later? How often does it changes? Still even if this is a case, make sure its updating is separated, and by doing that you will still have `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about nested streams using two short-circuiting `anyMatch` calls using a `Predicate`:

```
boolean test = list.stream()
    .map(FirstObject::getLastName)
    .anyMatch(y -> list2.stream()
             .map(SecondObject::getStuName)
             .anyMatch(x -> x.equals(y)));

test2.setBool(test);
```